# How to bind json object with variable in typescript Angular2?

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I have one json file and i want to bind with some variable to show on UI.

```
  testjson=  {"date":1468497879354,"faulty":"F-3","mileage":"150,900 mls","search":[]}
```

and in html

```
<div>
<span>{{ testjson }}</span><--- here i am getting above json object
Date:{{date}}
Faulty:{{faulty}}
Mileage: {{mileage}}
<div>
```

How do i bind so that i can get perticular object value ??

Comment: you will have to parse the json `angular.fromJson`

Comment: I  also did with parsing i couldnt get value for perticular object
testjson  = JSON.parse(testjson );
this.assign =testjson .date

Comment: simply using `testjson?.date`

Comment: I did that way but it showing me error RIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mileage' of undefined

Comment: <div *ngIf="testjson">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<div>
   <span>lala</span>
   Date:{{testjson.date}}
   Faulty:{{testjson.faulty}}
   Mileage: {{testjson.mileage}}
<div>
```

[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eeJI0wcVTxFNlXnjXQE4?p=info)

Comment: I did that way but it showing me error RIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mileage' of undefined

Comment: Can you please provide an example, cause as you see in plunker all works. May be you forget to fill testjson with some data?

Answer (score 0):

The values may be obtained directly using string interpolation.

```
{{testjson.date}}
{{testjson.faulty}}
```

etc...

that's it :)